# Excel/Sheets Consecutive Count Based on Two Conditions (function?)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Sheet, and I'm trying to see if it's possible to get a consecutive count outputted in a third column based on the values  of two other columns.

[image: This is an example layout]

My columns are:

**Column A:** Will have a handful of text values that are "grouped" together. Likely around 30 of the same value, until it changes to another value. In the image above, these are text1, and text2.

**Column B:** Will have one of 3 values assigned to each value in column A. In the image above, these are id1, id2, id3.

**Column C:** Will output a consecutive count based on the values of the first two columns. My hope is that if there are multiple ID1,ID2 in consecutive order, they'll repeat that first +1 value; while ID3 is always plus 1 to the count.  This is what I am trying to show in column C in the layout image above.

I've hit a wall with trying to accomplish this with various COUNTIF iterations.

Thanks for any help, or any better ideas to accomplish something similar.

*(I'm hoping for a formula, but open to being pointed into a direction for a script if that's the only way).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following formula:

```
=IF(A2=A1;IF(OR(B2="id3";B2<>B1);C1+1;C1);1)
```

[image]

Comment: Very simple but yet effective approach :)

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to do this as an array formula. I used offset ranges for column B in the first Countifs to check for a change in value but this made it a little awkward to get equal-sized arrays:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(A2:A="","",
  countifs({"";B2:B}<>{B2:B;""},true,{A2:A;""},A2:A,row(A:A),"<"&row(A2:A),{B2:B;""},"<>id3")+
  countifs(A2:A,A2:A,row(A2:A),"<="&row(A2:A),B2:B,"=id3")
))
```

[image]